# make the page scroll to show the full contents of a div element?

Tags: jquery-selectors

I'm using a simple javascript toggle function to expand a div to show its contents. If the div is near the bottom of the screen, it expands and some of the div disappears off the screen.

How can I get the page to automatically scroll down to make sure the div is in view?

Answer (score 0):

Each element on your page, including your `DIV`, will have a set of offset values relative to the document. You can get these via the [`$.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method. This will give you the x and y coordinates to the element on the page.

There are many plugins that exist in the wild (such as [`$.scrollTo()`](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) by Ariel Flesler) which will animate scrolling of your page for you, and even do so via a set of provided coordinates. You would join these two items together to automate a scrolling to the offset coordinates of your `DIV`.

Just make sure your `DIV` isn't taller than your viewport, or else you'll need to scroll even more to see all of it.